# Transitioning from Visitor to Spousal Visa in Canada for a PhD Student's Spouse

Tags: canada, bangladeshi-citizens

Travel Stack Exchange Community,

I am a PhD student currently studying at the University of British Columbia in Canada under a study permit. I am seeking advice regarding visa processes for my wife.

**Here is the situation:**

- My wife is planning to apply for a visitor visa to come to Canada from our home country (Bangladesh).
- We are considering applying for a spousal sponsorship (spouse visa) for her once she is in Canada.

**I have a few questions regarding this plan:**

1. Is it feasible for my wife to enter Canada on a visitor visa and then transition to a spousal sponsorship while in Canada?
2. What are the key considerations we should be aware of when transitioning from a visitor visa to a spousal visa in Canada?
3. If my wife's visitor visa expires while the spousal sponsorship application is in process, what steps should we take to ensure she maintains legal status in Canada?
4. Are there any implications for applying for a spousal sponsorship after entering Canada on a visitor visa that we should be aware of?

Any insights or experiences shared by those who have navigated a similar situation would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there are specific resources or official guidelines that might be helpful, please do share.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you would get better answers on our [expatriates.se] site which deals with stidying and living abroad long term.

Answer (score 0):

> We are considering applying for a spousal sponsorship (spouse visa) for her once she is in Canada.

Only Canadian citizens and permanent residents can sponsor their spouse and certain other family members for permanent residence. You, as a study permit holder, cannot sponsor anyone.

Although I understand what you mean (see later), but using the term spousal sponsorship or spouse visa is going to be bring much unneeded confusion for you. All government websites and most people you talk to will assume you are a citizen or PR who are trying to bringing your family here permanently.

> apply for a visitor visa

Another terminology to clarify is the visitor visa. A *visitor visa*, or temporary resident visa, in Canada is a document that allows you to board the plane and seek entry as a temporary resident (tourist, short business trip, worker and/or student).

What you probably mean is the visitor *status* (like a tourist). You do not need to have a valid visa to have a valid and legal status to stay in Canada.
A study or work permit or a visitor record is a status document. **The expiry of your status is also not the same as the date on your visitor visa.**

For example, if your visa expires but your work or study permit is valid, you can stay in Canada until its expiry, but you generally cannot re-enter without a valid visa (with some exceptions). If your work or study permit expires, or the period of stay granted by the border officer expires, you generally must leave Canada despite that your visitor visa is still valid.

> I am a PhD student currently studying at the University of British Columbia in Canada under a study permit.

I assume, instead, that you are trying to bringing your wife to Canada to accompany you during your studies, and possibly, for her to work in Canada. She will be, like you, a temporary resident in Canada.

The spouse of a study permit holder is eligible for an open work permit, provided that the study permit is issued for a graduate study program (since January 22, 2024). The open work permit allows the spouse to stay and work in most occupations (excluding e.g. sex work) in Canada without additional approval or notification to the immigration. It is usually valid for as long as the other spouse's study permit.

> Is it feasible for my wife to enter Canada on a visitor [status] and then transition to a [spousal work permit] while in Canada?

Yes, many people do this. It is also possible to apply directly for a work permit outside Canada. The processing time depends on your country though. In some countries, the visitor visa takes already quite long to process that you may want to just apply for the work permit at the same time to not delay further when she finally enters Canada.

> What are the key considerations we should be aware of when transitioning from a visitor visa to a spousal visa in Canada?

She must not work before receiving the approval for the work permit. To stay in Canada legally, she must submit the application for the work permit before her visitor status expires.

> If my wife's visitor visa expires while the spousal sponsorship application is in process, what steps should we take to ensure she maintains legal status in Canada?

If she submit the work permit application (or another application extending her stay) before the expiry of her visitor status, she will maintain her legal status in Canada until a decision is made on her work permit application.

To be precise, the work permit application must be submitted before midnight UTC (not any Canadian time) on the date the applicant’s status expires. If you find that confusing, just prepare early and **do not wait until the last day to submit**.

> Are there any implications for applying for a spousal sponsorship after entering Canada on a visitor visa that we should be aware of?

Your wife should submit a copy of your study permit and proof of financial resources (from her or you or jointly), and of course the marriage certificate.
If you got married after your study permit was approved, expect greater scrutiny since it is often an indicator that the relationship might not be genuine.